# HIGHCHARTS How to to make separate colors for shaded region and the line in Area Graph

Tags: highcharts

I have to set separate colours in the Area Graph for the shaded region and the line. How can i do this with Highcharts.

Below is the sample[image]

Comment: what about http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series/ - the colors are stored in the `stops` property.

Comment: @MartinSchneider Thanks a lot, I am just looking for this only.

Answer (score 1):

follow the below code:

set below code in your javascript and change colors that you want like...

```
fillColor : {
   linearGradient : {x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
   stops : [ [0, '#2a2a2b'], [1, '#3e3e40']],
}
```

below color is assign to line

> [0, '#2a2a2b']

while

> [1, '#3e3e40']

above one is for shaded region

I'm sure this will help you... you just need to add this code and change you color code that you like...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

What you need is [areaspline](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.areaspline) property of Highcharts with dark theme option.

Here is an example;

```
$(function () {
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function (data) {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate over time'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                    'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Exchange rate'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: {
                        x1: 0,
                        y1: 0,
                        x2: 0,
                        y2: 1
                    },
                    stops: [
                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                },
                marker: {
                    radius: 2
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                threshold: null
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: data
        }]
    });
});
```

And [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xL5b46z/) is the live form of above example.

What is important here is;

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/4.2.5/themes/dark-unica.js"></script>
```

line; which gives the **dark theme** to the chart.